# Identify Mac circa 1993 Word Processing Application

Tags: mac, file-format

We have some circa 1993 documents we need to access at work, but cannot determine the application used to create them. They were produced on Apple Mac, and the 3 1/2" floppy discs we have contain 3 files (with no extension), as follows:

- Info
- Files
- Directory

Unfortunately as these are such common terms, Google searches have to date been unsuccessful. It should be some sort of word processing application, as similar but smaller documents were done in MS-Word for Mac.

EDIT: File details info added in a comment below. A google search of the "X-Pert v2.0.1 apple mac" suggests Quark XPress might be a possible answer.

Comment: How did you list the contents of that floppy? What are the sizes of those files?

Comment: take a look at the content of `Info` and your files with a simple text editor. This may help.

Comment: If you're using Mac OS X or other Unix variant, you could run the [**file**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/file.1.html) command on those files and see what it suggests.

Comment: Are you sure the floppy is read correctly? You could adapt [this guide](http://www.emaculation.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=8208) to try and open it with MiniVMac.

Comment: My boss did the read from floppy, using a Mac Powerbook I think (can get the model details if required). The doc in question spanned 2 floppies, done as an old mac zip format. The 'Info' file is only 366 bytes - the only obvious clue in there is "X-Pert v2.0.1". The 'Files' file (689 kB) contains the document content. The 'Directory' file (655 kB) starts with some binary data, but then the bulk of the file is the character ö repeated.

Comment: Tried QuarkXPress to no avail. Alas still have no better ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Beware that classic Mac OS files each had 3 separate parts, all 3 of which usually needed to remain intact for the file to operate correctly:

- **Data Fork:** This was the usual contents of a file like you'd see on other platforms (Windows, Unix). For example, a plain text file would have its entire text in the data fork.
- **Resource Fork:** this was a secondary file data stream containing structured data known as "resources". This could be metadata like thumbnails or custom icons or author information, or it could be data that enhances what's in the Data Fork. For example, the popular "TeachText/SimpleText" format of styled text would store all the styling information and included graphics in the resource fork, while leaving the plain text in the Data Fork.
- **Finder Info:** this was a 32-byte data structure that stored the the HFS filesystem that contained a few pieces of critical metadata about the file, such as its Type and Creator codes (4 bytes each, typically 4 printable 7-bit ASCII charaters, or possibly 8-bit ASCII characters assumed to be in MacRoman encoding). It also contained a set of bit flags specifying whether it was supposed to be invisible, or write-locked, and a few other things.

Whatever method you use to get those files from the old diskettes onto a modern machine, you should probably be careful to keep all 3 of those parts of the file intact.

If you still have the Finder Info intact, you can look at the type/creator codes for the files, and probably still find listings online for what those mean. Type/creator codes were what classic Mac OS used instead of earlier ideas like filename extensions, or later ideas like MIME types.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but to date can't really see that it fits with the files we have.